# Make output of print_topics shows unicode character

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, nltk, gensim

When I show the output of ldamodel learnt by gensim

```
ldamodel = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus, num_topics=2, id2word = dictionary, passes=20)
ldamodel.print_topics(num_topics=2, num_words=4)
```

It will show all unicode character with \u

```
[(0,
  u'0.128*"dddf" + 0.128*"\u4f60\u597d" + 0.046*"o" + 0.046*"love"'),
 (1,
  u'0.057*"\u0646\u062f" + 0.057*"\u0627\u06cc\u0646\u0647" + 0.057*"\u0646\u0645\u06cc" + 0.057*"\u0628\u06cc\u0637\u0631\u0641\u0647"')]
```

Those unicode characters are chinese or persian characters, how should I make it appear as those characters?

Comment: Easiest solution, use the latest Python 3.